# How to hold the thread execution until asynchronous thread return callback

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, executorservice

I have scenario as depicted in the below diagram

[image]

Here main thread ismy java application.it opens one WM thread for execution.
WM handling task execution.he needs to call number of task for execution.
Suppose it contains task T1,T2,T3

T3 is dependent on T2 and T2 is dependent on T1.
WM first call RM to perform task execution of T1. T1 can give response in paging or be after completion of T1.

By question is how can I wait for T1 to complete and then start T2's execution.and how can I notify to WM when T1 partially complete sends data in paging.

This is the simple scenario but in case of T1,T2,T3,T4. T3 is dependent on T1 and T2.

Code :

```
public class TestAsync implements TaskCallBack {
    public static ExecutorService exService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
        Task t1 = new Task();
        t1.doTask(new TestAsync());

    }

    public static ExecutorService getPool(){
        return exService;
    }

    @Override
    public void taskCompleted(String obj) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}

class Task {
 public void doTask(TaskCallBack tcb) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
     FutureTask<String> ft = new FutureTask<>(new Task1());
     TestAsync.getPool().execute(ft);
     tcb.taskCompleted(ft.get());
 }

}

class Task1 implements Callable<String>{

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());               
        return "done";
    }

  interface TaskCallBack{
      public void TaskCompleted(String obj);
  }

}
```

Comment: if T3 can't start until T2 is finished, and T2 can't start until T1 is finished, why not just run them all in the same thread?

Comment: because T1 , T2 , T3 are doing different task and so many task I need to perform parallely.

Comment: "how can I wait for T1 to complete and then start T2's execution" --> by far the easiest way to do that is to run them in the same thread. you could use a BlockingQueue to pass data between the threads, but that seems over-complicated for the problem as stated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty interesting topic. I faced similar problem developing highly parallel network packet processing solution. I'll share my findings, but before that I should say it is always a bad idea to use some kind of ad-hoc solution for any parallel system.

Debugging, optimisation and further development might become a nightmare without proper architecture support. Let's say we have three dependent tasks:

[image]

**First solution**

will be to to introduce `composite or compound task` abstraction, in order to let dependent tasks be executed in a proper order and get rid of delays, waiting/blocking, complex task management, etc.

[image]

I will use simplified code in order to illustrate this approach:

```java
/**
 * Defines a high-level task contract. 
 * Let's pretend it is enough to have it this simple.
 */
interface Task extends Runnable {

}

/**
 * Defines a simple way to group dependent tasks.
 * 
 * Please note, this is the simplest way to make sure dependent tasks will be
 * executed in a specified order without any additional overhead.
 */
class CompoundTasks implements Task {

    private List<Task> tasks = ...;

    public void add(Task task) {
        tasks.add(task);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(Task t : tasks) {
           t.run();
        }
    }        
}
```

**Second solution**

will be to let tasks have explicit dependencies and make executors aware of that. Basically, the rule is quite simple - if task has unresolved dependencies it should be postponed. This approach can be easily implemented and works pretty fine.

[image]

Please note, second solution will introduce a tiny performance penalty due to the fact some resources will be needed to verify tasks, manage queue, etc.

Let's evolve our task-based approach:

```java
/**
 * Defines yet another abstraction to make dependencies 
 * visible and properly tracked. 
 * 
 */
abstract class DependentTask implements Task {

    private List<DependentTask> dependencies = ...;

    public void addDependency(DependentTask task) {
        dependencies.add(task);
    }

    /**
     * Verifies task can be processed. 
     */
    public boolean hasDependenciesResolved() {
        boolean result = true;
        for(DependentTask t : dependencies) {
            if(!t.hasDependenciesResolved()) {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public abstract void run();
}

/**
 * Implements a very basic queue aware of task dependencies.
 * 
 * Basically, the idea is just to avoid any blocking state. If task can't
 * be processed (because of unresolved dependencies) it should be 
 * postponed and verified later.
 */
class TaskQueue<T extends DependentTask> implements Runnable {        
    private Queue<T> queue = ...;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            if(!queue.isEmpty()) {

                T task = queue.poll();

                // Verify all dependencies have been resolved.
                if(task.hasDependenciesResolved()) {
                    task.run();         // process task if there is no unresolved
                                        // dependencies
                }else{
                    queue.add(task);    // return task to the queue
                }

            }else{
                // sleep for some reasonable amount of time
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Both approaches are easily traceable, so you always will be able to understand what is going on.

Comment: hey @Renat Gilmanov thanks for answer. can you please share more in coding.

Comment: Sure, will provide additional details

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of tasks for T1 and T2, you can use a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Your best option would probably be to wait before adding T2 tasks to the executor until all T1 tasks have completed (same for T2 -> T3).

If you cant change the adding code, you could also make each T2 task wait until all T1 tasks are completed, but that will lead to liveness issues (executor threadpool filled with nothing but sleeping threads) if the tasks are added unordered.